# Problem inserting array of child node in push ()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
export const createCharacter = (username, name, sex, vocation, achievementPoints, world) => {
    return (dispath) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('dev7@gmail.com', '123123')
            .then(value => {
                firebase.database().ref('/sales/')
                    .push({
                        owner: username,
                        character: [
                            {
                                name: name,
                                sex: sex,
                                vocation: vocation,
                                achievementPoints: achievementPoints,
                                world: world
                            }
                        ],
                        price: 21.12
                    })
                    .then(() => {

                    })
            })
            .catch(error => alert(error))
    }
}
```

...and with it I got the following result:

[image: Result in firebase]

When I try to execute the action method for the first time, I catch this error:

> Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property `sales.character.0.name`

But when I execute it without refresh for the second time, the push is successful.

**My question is**, how should I push in order to not generate this UID?

Comment: Please add the code where you call `createCharacter` and where you call the function that it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an object to Firebase, the values of the properties can be a value or null. They can not be undefined,

```
firebase.database().ref('/sales/')
                    .push({
                        owner: username || null,
                        character: [
                            {
                                name: name || null,
                                sex: sex || null,
                                vocation: vocation || null,
                                achievementPoints: achievementPoints || null,
                                world: world || null
                            }
                        ],
                        price: 21.12
                    })
```